# tcpdf on Lumen Class 'PDF' not found

Tags: tcpdf, lumen

I created a new project with Lumen 5.4.7 and I added the TCPDF library from `elibyy/tcpdf-laravel` version 5.4.2 (with Lumen support):

```
composer require elibyy/tcpdf-laravel "5.4.2"
```

I enabled the Facades and Service Provider in `bootstrap/app.php` with

```
$app->withFacades();
$app->register(Elibyy\TCPDF\ServiceProvider::class);
```

And I created a basic Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use \PDF;

class PdfController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a test PDF file.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function createTestPdf()
    {
      PDF::SetTitle('Hello World');
      PDF::AddPage();
      PDF::Write(0, 'Hello World');
      PDF::Output('hello_world.pdf');

      echo "Fatto!";
    }
}
```

with a basic route:

```
$app->get('pdf', 'PdfController@createTestPdf');
```

But when I try to access to `/pdf` I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDF' not found in /Users/m/Documents/Projects/lumen-pdf/app/Http/Controllers/PdfController.php on line 15

(1/1) FatalErrorException
Class 'PDF' not found
in PdfController.php (line 15)
at Application->handleShutdown()
in RegistersExceptionHandlers.php (line 54)
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}()
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

One line was missing into `bootstrap/app.php` to add a new **class_alias** for **Elibyy\TCPDF\Facades\TCPDF** to **PDF**:

```
class_alias('Elibyy\TCPDF\Facades\TCPDF', 'PDF');
```

Thanks!